# HTML Image button complete each other

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

Am using MVC4
I want to have map in my page where each region is Image button.
I already have each region as image my question is:
How I place the image of region so that are all region complete each other? 
Like what I have hier with 2 regions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoNQy.png

I have about 6 of them

Comment: wrap all images in a position relative container and use position absolute, top, left, right, bottom to complete your puzle

Comment: Oky I think this is HTML.right? how I defined the pixel for each?there is no other way where i could get HTML code after organize the images the way i want(sorry am new to HTML).

Comment: It's CSS :) try searching for CSS Positioning

Comment: Would be good if you could post the HTML/CSS that you have coem up with so far.

Comment: Is it an option to use a single image and use the `<map>` + `<area>` html tags to make regions clickable?

Comment: No i know the image map... but i want it image button..

Comment: I see many tutorial in how to have image side by side..BUT in my situation the image is shaped and are complete each other ..Can u advice me to helpful tutorial.